# How do I stop Javascript from transforming my date to a division?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass two arrays, which I pass through the view model, into an array composed of arrays with the values of the arrays. (at the end another problem)

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4]
+
["Miguel", "Lucia", "Luis", "Charles"]
into 
[["1","Miguel"],["2","Lucia"],etc...
```

Here is my code:

```
script>
    var dataset = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Data.Count(); i++) {
        var dato = [@Model.Data[117].ToString(),@Model.Labels[117].ToString()]
        dataset.push(dato)
    }
    console.log(dataset)
</script>
```

The problem it's that the @Model.Labels has a format of DD/MM/YYYY, and it's making the division, giving the value of for example 28 divided by 03 divided by 2019.

Well and I also have the problem of running through the arrays since it says that i doesn't exist in the current context.

```
for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Data.Count(); i++) {
        var dato = [@Model.Data[i].ToString(),@Model.Labels[i].ToString()]
        dataset.push(dato)
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you combine them server side and just pass JSON result to a javascript variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Razor code is executed server side before the page is sent to the browser. So:

```
var dato = [@Model.Data[117].ToString(),@Model.Labels[117].ToString()]
```

Will actually be:

```
var dato = [somevalue,28/03/2019]
```

Which is why the date parts then get divided. You will need to escape the string.

Same problem for your second issue. `@Model.Data[i].ToString()` will be evaluated server side and not when the JavaScript runs.

Comment: Ok, i will do it in the server, it's easier, but I was lazy, THANKS